# Spring Boot: purpose of @EnableSocial anotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-social

in my Spring Boot app I am implementing the social login using Spring Social (1.1.4.RELEASE), I have following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {
```

I see that **@EnableSocial** calls **@Import(SocialConfiguration.class)**, but when I remove annotation **@EnableSocial** the social login works the same and **SocialConfiguration** is used anyway.

Comment: Have you defined the properties spring.social.facebook.appId and spring.social.facebook.appSecret in application.properties, for example?

Comment: Yes, I have ti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say without knowing more about your code, but even if you don't use `@EnableSocial`, Spring Boot will still assume you mean to use it if you provide sufficient social information (I'll use Facebook as an example here):

1. Your project depends on `org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook` directly or transitively through for example `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-facebook`.
2. You specify information that the app can use to connect to the social network site. To figure out exactly what you need for Spring Boot to automatically configure it, you should check out the AutoConfiguration class for the social site in question, for example `FacebookAutoConfiguration`.

By the way, here's an example on how to get it working without `@EnableSocial`. Does it look similar to your setup? https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/

Comment: Thank! I see that in FacebookAutoConfiguration there is @EnableSocial annotation.